# Nginx, check for request method without using IF?

Tags: nginx, http, webdav

I am trying to optimize my Nginx config but ran into an issue I don't know how to fix. I have a folder `/images` on my server from which I deliver various static files for a website. The same folder though is also used in order to upload files via WebDAV.

Therefore, I have have to check for every request is the static file exists AND if the request method is `GET`, I deliver the file. Otherwise, I assume that the request was related to WebDAV (such as PUT, etc). See this sample:

```
if ($uri ~* ^/images)         { set $getimages "${getimages}A"; }
if ($request_method = GET)    { set $getimages "${getimages}B"; }
if ($getimages = "AB") {
    rewrite ^ $uri$args last;
}
```

This above sample works fine. But I was wondering if there's another way to do this, without using IF. Given the [IfIsEvil reference](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) in the Nginx Wiki

Ideas anyone?

Comment: Why are you doing _any_ of this?

Comment: If is _not_ evil, if used outside a location block! Even inside a location block, it can be used with _return_ and _rewrite_ directives!

Comment: @Pothi I guess you are right. I use it outside a location block anyways. So it should be fine I suppose. Thx again for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Re-post [comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/543466/nginx-check-for-request-method-without-using-if#comment626120_543466) from [Pothi](https://serverfault.com/users/102173/pothi) as CW</sub>

`If` is not *evil*, if used outside a `location` block! Even inside a `location` block, it can be used with `return` and `rewrite` directives!

Snippet from IfIsEvil page

> Directive `if` has problems when used in `location` context, in some cases it doesn't do what you expect but something completely different instead. In some cases it even **segfaults**. It's generally a good idea to avoid it if possible.
>
> The only 100% safe things which may be done inside if in `location` context are:
>
> ```
> return ...;
> rewrite ... last;
> ```
>
> Anything else may possibly cause unpredictable behaviour, including potential **SIGSEGV**.